# I need to find related data from 2 associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

So, I am returning 2 different multi-dimensional arrays from 2 separate db calls.(Can't use a join because of our specific API for db calls)
I need to search through 2nd array and if a value matches that of a value in the first array, I need to append the related data to that row in first array for display in datatable. I have tried numerous things to just get the values to show. Here is what my arrays look like and where I am at with it.

Array 1

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","message":"Successfully read","data":
[{"ordnbr":"12345",
"custid":"CUSTID #",
"custname":"My Customers Name",
"custordnbr":"54321",
"slsperid":"ID",
"orddate":"2015-05-14",
"shipdate":"2015-06-03",
"dtrdy":"2015-05-29",
"carrier":"Some Carrier",
"totord":"21703",
"shipped":"4341",
"notes":"These are notes",
"siteid":"Some Site",
"orderstatus":"RDY"},

{"ordnbr":"23456",
"custid":"Anoter Customer",
"custname":"Another Customers Name",
"custordnbr":"65432",
"slsperid":"ID2",
"orddate":"2015-05-19",
"shipdate":"2015-06-05",
"dtrdy":"2015-06-05",
"carrier":"Another Carrier",
"totord":"98875",
"shipped":"0",
"notes":" ",
"siteid":"Another Site",
"orderstatus":"GR"},
```

etc... The list goes on as there are numerous records.

Second array looks kind of like this(var_dump) I realize this is an array of objects but am casting each line to array.

```
array(41) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2923 (15) {
    ["trknbr"]=>
    string(12) "7890"
    ["siteid"]=>
    string(3) "This Site"
    ["flatrate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ratemile"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["miles"]=>
    string(3) "822"
    ["covered"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["dateship"]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
    ["trkco"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totalchrg"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["fuelchrg"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tarp"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["shipdirection"]=>
    string(3) "out"
    ["comments"]=>
    NULL
    ["custname"]=>
    string(30) "CustName"
    ["detail"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2922 (7) {
        ["trknbr"]=>
        string(12) "BR549"
        ["ordnbr"]=>
        string(6) "12345"
        ["dtrelease"]=>
        string(10) "2015-06-04"
        ["custid"]=>
        string(6) "Custid"
        ["shipto"]=>
        string(13) "Some City"
        ["slsperid"]=>
        string(2) "WE"
        ["comments"]=>
        string(21) "Truck # 2 of 5
$2360"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2916 (15) {
    ["trknbr"]=>
    string(12) "34563"
    ["siteid"]=>
    string(3) "My Other Site"
    ["flatrate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ratemile"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["miles"]=>
    string(3) "244"
    ["covered"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["dateship"]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
    ["trkco"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totalchrg"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["fuelchrg"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tarp"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["shipdirection"]=>
    string(3) "out"
    ["comments"]=>
    NULL
    ["custname"]=>
    string(25) "Another Customer"
    ["detail"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#2830 (7) {
        ["trknbr"]=>
        string(12) "34563"
        ["ordnbr"]=>
        string(6) "34578"
        ["dtrelease"]=>
        string(10) "2015-06-08"
        ["custid"]=>
        string(6) "wwweee"
        ["shipto"]=>
        string(12) "Another City"
        ["slsperid"]=>
        string(3) "RRR"
        ["comments"]=>
        string(31) "DO NOT SHIP BEFORE 6/8
$  769P"
      }
    }
  }
```

So what I need to do is, for example, if the ordnbr field is the same for any 2 arrays, I need to append a couple fields from the 2nd array onto the first array. Right now, I am just trying to get the data to return so I can make the comparison and it doesn't seem to be comparing. I have tried using a foreach loop and if array1->ordnbr == array2->ordnbr, then do something... That doesn't work. Tried using in_array and searching for array1->ordnbr in array2.
Nothing I have done works. Can someone please tell me in what direction I should proceed to make these comparisons?
Thanks in advance.

I may not have been real clear on what I need to do... Ok... With Array 1(which did start out as a JSON object but which I converted to multidimensional array using json_decode), I need all rows regardless of whether they match Array 2 or not. However, if ordnbr matches an ordnbr on a row in Array2, then I need to include some data from that row in Array2 into the corresponding row of Array1.

Comment: Can you please show us what you have attempted so far? Besides, the first one is not an array, but an object. And it sounds like a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is to create 2 associative arrays, one for each array with key is `ordnbr` and value is the whole object contain `ordnbr`. For example:

```
$arr1 = array()
foreach ($input1["data"] as $row){
    $arr1[$row["ordnbr"]] = $row;
}
```

The do the same for your second array `$arr2`. After that, a simple foreach would do the job

```
foreach ($arr1 as $order_number => $row){
    if in_array($order_number, $arr2){
        // $row2 will have the same $order_number as $row1
        $row2 = $arr2[$order_number];
        // then do whatever you need here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I may not have been real clear on what I need to do... Ok... With Array 1(which did start out as a JSON object but which I converted to multidimensional array using json_decode), I need all rows regardless of whether they match Array 2 or not. However, if ordnbr matches an ordnbr on a row in Array2, then I need to include some data from that row in Array2 into the corresponding row of Array1.

Comment: That's exactly the code for. Inside the `if` statement you would check if `ordnbr` is present in `$arr2`. If yes you update $row, otherwise do nothing. In the end you will need to store `$row` in another array.

Comment: I encountered a delay on this project as I had another project ongoing.... So, here is the issue I am having with the above code. I do see where it could work. However, because of the depth of the second array, the ordnbr field in the second array is never compared.... Note the first row in the second array above. There is an array and then there is a sub-array so to speak that is the detail. Detail is where the ordnbr column is. I have tried using, in your example, $arr2['detail']['ordnbr'] as with a multidimensional array, but that doesn't work. I am lost and can't get to that key->value...